# Export to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: export, unreal-engine

Im very new to Blender. I create a Room for UE4 but when I export it to Engine Inside this room is good but when look it from outside you can not see walls and Light goes throw it to inside. Sorry for bad english. What can I do to fix this?
[image: this is ftom Unreal]

[image: And its Blender]

Comment: Have you tried the add-on I suggested? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208614/blender-for-unreal-settings#comment352082_208614

Comment: Yeah i try one. I think its a problem with my asset in blender. for the floor and roof I used bridge and F. Im new to it, is that make a problem for exporting to unreal?